# Simple HTML/JS collision detection not working

Tags: javascript, html

First post, so I'm sorry if my etiquette is bad.
I'm trying to set up a simple HTML/JavaScript page with collision detection between two 2D objects with one dimension of movement and I can't figure out why it's not doing anything.

Code snippet with all the goods:

```js
var field = document.getElementById("battlefield");
var allies = document.getElementsByClassName("ally");
var enemies = document.getElementsByClassName("enemy");
var fighters = document.getElementsByClassName("fighter");

var c1speed = 3; //Speed of fighters

function spawna1() { //spawns a blue fighter
  node = document.createElement("div");
  node.classList.add("fighter", "ally", "c1");
  field.appendChild(node);
}

spawna1();

function spawne1() { //spawns a red fighter
  node = document.createElement("div");
  node.classList.add("fighter", "enemy", "e1");
  field.appendChild(node);
}

spawne1();

var movea = setInterval(function() {
  for (i = 0; i < allies.length; i++) { //Move blue
    allies[i].style.left = (allies[i].offsetLeft + c1speed) + "px";
    if (allies[i].offsetLeft > window.innerWidth + 200) {
      allies[i].remove();
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) { //Move red
    enemies[i].style.left = (enemies[i].offsetLeft - c1speed) + "px";
    if (enemies[i].offsetLeft < -200) {
      enemies[i].remove();
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < fighters.length; i++) { //Collision detection, theoretically
    for (j = i + 1; j < fighters.length; j++) {
      if (fighters[i].offsetLeft < fighters[j].offsetLeft + fighters[j].width || //If i=red and j=blue
        fighters[i].offsetLeft + fighters[i].width > fighters[j].offsetLeft) { //or if i=blue and j=red
        fighters[i].remove(); //Remove the fighters when they collide
        fighters[j].remove();
      }
    }
  }
}, 20);
```

```css
html,
body,
#page-container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#page-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #c5c5c5;
}

#game {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  z-index: 99;
}

#battlefield {
  width: 100%;
  height: 67%;
}

#lower {
  width: 100%;
  height: 33%;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.ally {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 33%;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
}

.enemy {
  position: absolute;
  left: 600px;
  bottom: 33%;
  background-color: red;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-container">
  <div id="game">
    <div id="battlefield">
    </div>
    <div id="lower">
      <button onclick="spawna1();spawne1()">SPAWN MORE</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The blue "fighter" should move right while the red moves left. On collision, they should both disappear.
Here's the basics of what I have (I highly recommend running the snippet):

```
var fighters = document.getElementsByClassName("fighter");

function spawna1() {
    node = document.createElement("div");
    node.classList.add("fighter", "ally", "c1");
    field.appendChild(node);
}

spawna1();

function spawne1() {
    node = document.createElement("div");
    node.classList.add("fighter", "enemy", "e1");
    field.appendChild(node);
}

spawne1();

var movea = setInterval(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < fighters.length; i++) {     //Hit detection formula
        for (j = i + 1; j < fighters.length; j++) {
            if (fighters[i].offsetLeft < fighters[j].offsetLeft + fighters[j].width ||
            fighters[i].offsetLeft + fighters[i].width > fighters[j].offsetLeft) {
                fighters[i].remove();    //remove fighters on collide
                fighters[j].remove();
            }
        }
    }
}, 20);
```

I really appreciate your time and patience. Thanks :D

Comment: `fighters[i/j].width` is not defined, use `offsetWidth` instead. Though that would introduce a new problem, all the elements the loop refers are not created (specifically `fighters[j]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution!

Since the blue and red objects were being assigned an `ally` and `enemy` class respectively when `spawn()` was called, I just had to change the collision detection to check `allies[i]` against `enemies[j]`. Here's the snippet:

```js
var field = document.getElementById("battlefield");
var allies = document.getElementsByClassName("ally");
var enemies = document.getElementsByClassName("enemy");
var fighters = document.getElementsByClassName("fighter");
var c10 = document.getElementById("c10");
var c1o = 1;
var c1 = {
  "a": 1,
  "d": 1,
  "s": 3,
  "o": 1,
  "si": 1500,
  "os": c1o
};
var ce1 = {
  "a": 1,
  "d": 1,
  "s": 3,
  "o": 1,
  "si": 1500,
  "os": c1o
};

function spawna1() {
  var spawna1int = setTimeout(function() {
    node = document.createElement("div");
    node.classList.add("fighter", "ally", "c1");
    field.appendChild(node);
    spawna1();
  }, (c1.si / c1.o));
}

spawna1();

function spawne1() {
  var spawna1int = setTimeout(function() {
    node = document.createElement("div");
    node.classList.add("fighter", "enemy", "c1");
    field.appendChild(node);
    spawne1();
  }, (ce1.si / ce1.o));
}

spawne1();

var movea = setInterval(function() {
  for (i = 0; i < allies.length; i++) { //Move A1
    allies[i].style.left = (allies[i].offsetLeft + c1.s) + "px";
    if (allies[i].offsetLeft > window.innerWidth + 200) {
      allies[i].remove(); //Remove when off screen
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) { //Move E1
    enemies[i].style.left = (enemies[i].offsetLeft - ce1.s) + "px";
    if (enemies[i].offsetLeft < -200) {
      enemies[i].remove(); //Remove when off screen
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < allies.length; i++) { //Hit detection, I hope
    for (j = 0; j < enemies.length; j++) {
      if (allies[i].offsetLeft < enemies[j].offsetLeft + enemies[j].offsetWidth &&
        allies[i].offsetLeft + allies[i].offsetWidth > enemies[j].offsetLeft) {
        //What should happen when they collide???
        if (allies[i].classList[1] == enemies[j].classList[1]) { //Friendly fire off
          return;
        }
        if (eval(allies[i].classList[2]).a > eval(enemies[j].classList[2]).d) { //if I attack is higher than J defense, kill J
          enemies[j].remove();
        }
        if (eval(enemies[j].classList[2]).a > eval(enemies[j].classList[2]).d) { //if J attack is higher than I defense, kill I
          allies[i].remove();
        }
        if (eval(enemies[j].classList[2]).a == eval(enemies[j].classList[2]).a &&
          eval(enemies[j].classList[2]).d == eval(enemies[j].classList[2]).d) { //if I and J are equal, kill both
          allies[i].remove();
          enemies[j].remove();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}, 20);
```

```css
html,
body,
#page-container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#page-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #c5c5c5;
}

#game {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  z-index: 99;
}

#battlefield {
  width: 100%;
  height: 67%;
}

#lower {
  width: 100%;
  height: 33%;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.ally {
  position: absolute;
  left: -150px;
  bottom: 33%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.enemy {
  position: absolute;
  left: 600px;
  bottom: 33%;
  background-color: red;
}

.c1 {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Welcome to Valhalla!</title>
  <meta name="author" content="beanamonster">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="halla.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="page-container">
    <div id="game">
      <div id="battlefield">

      </div>
      <div id="lower">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="halla.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I added a lot overnight, so this probably won't make sense anymore. But essentially, we assign the red objects a class and the blue objects a different class. Have the the `for` cycle through the blues while the nested `for` checks those against reds based on their respective classes.